# Subscribers On Parent Not Child

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

We have about 2.8 million records total in our Parent Account but when I add up all of the subscribers from our child accounts they equal about 2.4 million.

The child accounts have different Profile Attributes for each to filer down who is allowed in the child account. My issue is that I've created a Group in the Parent account that filters everyone who does NOT have a profile attribute that aligns with a child account but I'm only getting about 17k records rather than the 400k I should be getting.

Is there any other way to filter or query for subscribers who exist ONLY in the parent account?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [_Subscriber](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) data view and the [_Enterpriseattribute](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5) data view to understand your data better

_EA dataview is how you can query profile attributes, linked on subscriberid to the _subscriber dataview

Comment: I created this query:

select
s.subscriberkey
from _EnterpriseAttribute a
inner join _Subscribers s on (s.subscriberID = a._SubscriberID)
WHERE 'StoreCode' is null

to try and find customers who do not have a store code and while I'm not getting any errors, I'm not seeing any records populate in my Data Extension. "StoreCode" is a profile attribute.

Comment: why do you have quotes around your field name?

Comment: ah good point, that fixed it thank you